# Can't run test due to ImportError

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have the following project structure:

```
|   .gitignore
|   README.md
|   call_test_outside.py
|   main.py
|   setup.cfg
|   setup.py
|- src
  |- PropTools
    |   __init__.py
    |   PropTools
      |   __init__.py
      |   SQLiteWrapper.py
      |   dates.py
      |   prices.py
      |- transactions.py
    |   config
      |   __init__.py
      |- settings.py
    |- tests
      |   __init__.py
      |- transactions_tests.py
```

**Problem:** When I run `transactions_tests.py` inside `tests` folder I get `ImportError`:

```
from ..PropTools.transactions import TransactionType, InstrumentType, get_transactions
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

But if I try to do the same from `call_test_outside.py` from root folder it works.

## Codes:

`transactions_test.py` code (in tests folder):

```
from ..PropTools.transactions import TransactionType, InstrumentType, get_transactions

print(get_transactions)
```

`call_test_outside.py` code:

```
from src.PropTools.tests import transactions_tests
    
print(transactions_tests.get_transactions)
```

How can or should I test the development of the package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/6385519

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that the directory above `transactions_tests.py` is `tests` so trying to access `PropTools` from there won’t work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Python resolves relative importing by `__name__` and `__package__` variables.

When you are executing `python src/PropTools/tests/transactions_tests.py` directly those are set to

```
__name__ = "__main__"
__package__ = None
```

But when you are executing the `python call_test_outside.py` and then importing

```
from src.PropTools.tests import transactions_tests
```

Those variables when `src/PropTools/tests/transactions_tests.py` is executing are set to

```
__name__ = "src.PropTools.tests.transactions_tests"
__package__ = "src.PropTools.tests"
```

So now the python interpreter knows the parent package of `transactions_tests.py` is `src.PropTools` and it can search for the `..PropTools.transactions` package.

You can find complete information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/13203169).